# STOP2 mode with FreeRTOS in STM32

Tags: stm32, freertos

I am developing a low power application with STM32L476 (with FreeRTOS). I am using SW4STM32 and STM32CubeMx.  I have gone through the Tickless idle mode example which uses sleep mode. I need more power saving, so i am planning to use STOP2 mode. Is it possible to use STOP2 mode along with FreeRTOS?

Comment: I would suggest the bare metal approach if you design the very low power application

Comment: since we need higher power optimization we are thinking about bare metal approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a low power timer if the tickless feature is enabled.

> Stop 0, Stop 1 and Stop 2 modes: SRAM1, SRAM2 and all registers
>   content areretained. All clocks in the VCOREdomain are stopped, the
>   PLL, the MSI, the HSI16 andthe HSE are disabled. The LSI and the LSE
>   can be kept running.

*Found in the STM32L4x6 reference manual, RM0351 Rev 6, p.164*

"Low Power RTOS For ARM Cortex-M MCUs" guide:
https://www.freertos.org/low-power-ARM-cortex-rtos.html

Comment: This seems to be a good approach. But for  higher power optimization we are moving towards bare metal approach

Comment: Above approach uses sleep mode for power saving. For designs that requires power saving in sleep mode, tickless idle mode can be used.